# Where to place JQuery Script in CakePHP to have it run after page loads (as opposed to in a header)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, qtip

Just started working on a CakePHP framework, am not very familiar with this particular architecture.

I have installed Qtip tooltips after Jquery.  I know that they are installed correctly, because I can trigger the correct behavior I want by running the following script in the console:

```
$("li.standardsList").qtip()
```

Seemingly, if I could only make this one script run inside Cake, all my problems would be solved.

Within the ctp (view) file, at the bottom of all the other header links, I have the following:

```
echo $this -> Html -> script('tagging-tool/applied-qtip.js');
```

And within the applied-qtip.js is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.standardsList").qtip();
});
```

Yet, I can't get that to work;  I tried adding in an alert inside the applied-qtip.js, and that did fire off successfuly.

After that, I tried putting the:

```
echo $this -> Html -> script('tagging-tool/applied-qtip.js');
```

at the end of the file, and then it appeared to just not run at all.

Any ideas of where to go from here?

Comment: At the end of the file? You mean before `</body>`, right?

Comment: I think before the body, yes.  That is one of the things that confuses me about Cake, I have to assume it's before the closing body tag, but since it's a framework, I'm not entirely sure.  Do you have a sense of how one could add such a tag after the body?

Comment: Well where are you echoing it? What file? Cake is still PHP and leaves a lot of it up to you, including HTML. It just puts it together nicely.

Comment: So the page in question would be called tagging-tool, so that call is outside of any html, only within PHP tags, at the top of tagging-tool.ctp  , which I guess is just a view page. Is there a more logical place to put something like that?

Comment: If you're using it in pages other than tagging-tool, then it belongs in the layout instead.

Comment: Ok, thankyou, I'll look into the difference and see if that changes it

Comment: I worked around and solved it.  I deleted the additional applied-qtip.js and just added in the $(.standardsList).qtip() into the location were .standardsList was generated

Comment: You should probably close the question if you can, since it was very specific to your setup and not a problem associated with the original title.

Comment: At any rate, glad you got it cleared up!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit hackneyed, but possibly this will help someone specifically in the future-

I removed the separate applied-qtip.js file altogether and added in the

```
$('.standardsList').qtip()
```

immediately after the creation of the item it was to be applied to (in this case, the li).

Thus, it was certain to be applied after those items were loaded, which apparently I was applying the qtip property before the items had been created.

For other cake user posterity, possibly such an item can be found in a parallel folder structure to my specific case:

app/webroot/js/tagging-tool/standards-component.js